# Android Week View Issue

Tags: java, android

I'm using this library : https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View

I'm new to Android, and I'm needing some help to solve this issue, I can't understand why
I'm getting this error:

> "cannot resolve symbol mWeekView"

If anyone have the answer, it would be appreciated.

Here is a screenshot :

[image: Screen]

EDIT : even with the implements, still getting this error

Comment: Please post code at text and not a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mWeekView` is object of `WeekView`  in your class. Add this->

```
WeekView mWeekView;
```

before `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare you view as a WeekView. Also add the following so it will load some default dummy event so you can at least try out the view (Put this in your oncreate()):

```
    WeekView mWeekView = (WeekView) findViewById(R.id.weekView);

    mWeekView.setOnEventClickListener(new WeekView.EventClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEventClick(WeekViewEvent event, RectF eventRect) {

        }
    });

    mWeekView.setMonthChangeListener(new MonthLoader.MonthChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public List<WeekViewEvent> onMonthChange(int newYear, int newMonth) {
            List<WeekViewEvent> events = new ArrayList<WeekViewEvent>();

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar1.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
            WeekViewEvent someEvent = new WeekViewEvent(1,"someEvent",calendar,calendar1);
            events.add(someEvent);
            return events;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the `mWeekView` field in your class.
Add this line to the start of the class (the next line after the `public class ...`):

```
private WeekView mWeekView;
```